# integral and mathematical expectation of $\operatorname{sech}⁡^2(x)$

Tags: integration, expectation

$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}$
How to deduce from :

$$\int_0^{+∞} \sech^2(x)e^{-λx}\,dx=\int_{-∞}^0 \sech^2(x)e^{λx}\,dx = \frac \lambda  2 \left(\psi\left[\frac{λ+2r}4\right]-\psi\left( \frac \lambda 4\right)\right)-1,$$

to the result:

$$∫_{-∞}^{+∞} \sech^2(rV_i) λ/2e^{-λV_i}dV_i=(λ/r)[(λ/2r)(ψ[(λ+2r)/4r]-ψ(λ/4r)-1]$$

finally,we have the mathematical expectation :$E[\sech^2(rV_i)]$ is equal to right side of the  equation,in other words,

$$E[\sech^2(rV_i)]=(λ/r)[(λ/2r)(ψ[(λ+2r)/4r]-ψ(λ/4r)-1].$$

where $\sech⁡(x)$ is defined as secant of hyperbolic function, $ψ(x)$ is Euler psi function and $r, λ$ are two constants.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think there should be no $ r $ in the first expression. Correcting this, change $ \lambda $ to $ \frac {\lambda} { r} $ to get new formula on the right. Then change the variable $ x $ to $ rV_i $.

Comment: Once you know the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)^2}$, that is just a change of variable.

Comment: Yes,you are right ,there is no $r$ in the first expression.Through your explanation, I understand the derivation process better now.Thank you so much.